# C++ IO file streams: writing from one file to another using operator<< and rdbuf()

Tags: c++, stl, fstream, ifstream

I have a question about copying data from one file to another in C++ (fstream) using operator<<. Here is a code snippet that works for me:

```
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>

    void writeTo(string &fname, ofstream &out){
        ifstream in;
        in.open(fname.c_str(),fstream::binary);
        if(in.good()){
            out<<in.rdbuf();
            in.close();
        }else{
            //error
        }
    }
```

I would like to be certain that after writing, the end of input file in stream `in` has been reached. However, if I test for `in.eof()`, it is `false`, despite the fact that checking the input and output files confirms that the entire contents has been properly copied over. Any ideas on how I would check for `in.eof()`?

Comment: `eof` is set when you attempt to read past the end of the input, not when you reach it.

Comment: Try maybe only "out << in;". Maybe working directly with the rdbuf() doesn't affect the flags of in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EOF-bit is set when trying to read a character, but none is available (i.e. you have already consumed everything in the string). Apparently `std::ostream::operator<<()` does not attempt to read past the end of the string, so the bit is never set.

You should be able to get around this by attempting to access the next character: add `in.peek()` before you check `in.eof()`. I have tested this fix and it works.

Comment: I would love to know why this is wrong, especially since my suggested fix works. It is widely documented that the EOF bit is not set when reading the last character in a file: only when you attempt to read past the end of the file.

Comment: I meant `operator<<`, since it is being used to read from `in`: `out << in.rdbuf()`. Since reading from the `in.rdbuf()` leaves `in` empty and does not set the EOF bit, attempting to read a single character (e.g. with `in.peek()`) will set the EOF bit [by attempting to read past the end of the stream].

Comment: OK, I have deleted all my comments, as I completely misunderstood what you were saying. Apologies.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for the discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Try `in.rdbuf()->sgetc() == EOF`.

Reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/streambuf/sgetc/

Answer (score 1):

The reason none of the status bits are set in the input file is because
you are reading through the `streambuf`, not the `istream`; the actual
reading takes place in the `ostream::operator<<`, which doesn't have
access to the `istream`.

I'm not sure it matters, however.  The input will be read until
`streambuf::sgetc` returns `EOF`.  Which would cause the `eofbit` to be
set in the `istream` if you were reading through the `istream`.  The
only thing which might prevent this if you were reading through the
`istream` is if `streambuf::sgetc` threw an exception, which would cause
`badbit` to be set in `istream`; there is no other mechanism provided
for an input `streambuf` to report a read error.  So wrap your `out <<
in.rdbuf()` in a `try ... catch` block, and hope that the implementation
actually does check for hardware errors.  (I haven't checked recently,
but a lot of early implementations totally ignored read errors, treating
them as a normal end of file.)

And of course, since you're literally reading bytes (despite the `<<`, I
don't see how one could call this formatted input), you don't have to
consider the third possible source of errors, a format error (such as
"abc" when inputing an int).